# How long does it take to build an app like Tinder?

Tags: native, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to develop a simple app like Tinder (http://vimeo.com/tinderapp/itstartshere), without chat, for IOS, Android and Windows. I'm wondering how long it would take according to these choices:

- a native app
- an hybrid app (assuming that I know HTML5, JS, jQuery)

What would I have to learn in addition if I choose the hybrid ?
According to you, what is the best choice for this kind of app ?
How much does it cost to build such apps ?

Answer (score -1):

Depends on the team you have available. can be done in less then a week using existing libraries. Cost will be between 2500 and 50k